Conditional formatting specific rows in a Power BI Matrix
I want to add row farmatting as shown in the attached image (this is not my BI file). I've read a lot of tips and tried to implement some of them, but I am not getting the result shown below.
The measure below is the closed I've got. But not good enough or close to what I'm looking for.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
CF Rows = 

IF  (HASONEVALUE('D Headers_Blob'[Detail])
    ,IF( FIRSTNONBLANK('D Headers_Blob'[Detail] , 1) = "Total Net Income"
        ,"lightgreen"
        ,"white"
    )
    ,BLANK()
)


https://kpisolutions.nl/finance-dashboard/?utm_term=power%20bi%20finance&utm_campaign=KPI-NL-Rapportages&utm_source=adwords&utm_medium=ppc&hsa_acc=9896799870&hsa_cam=18518544447&hsa_grp=141750187123&hsa_ad=673850509195&hsa_src=g&hsa_tgt=kwd-389193646492&hsa_kw=power%20bi%20finance&hsa_mt=p&hsa_net=adwords&hsa_ver=3&gad_source=1&gclid=CjwKCAjwzIK1BhAuEiwAHQmU3gC9_Z1CHJa_-TaTR2LVfIm4P7-5m13AWo8P0Q6WYPmeu7Z_lmi2EhoCiG0QAvD_BwE

You need to explain all the conditionals that you want because with this information I can't fully get the others.
If you want to change the background colour of the matrix values you can add more than one rules to do so. Choose the value that you wanna modify in the visualization tab --> conditional format --> background colour.
Inside this menu you can select your rules to change the colour as you please. For example.
Conditional Rules
Matrix with the colour conditional rules
